# Twitter mining - how many API 'get-requests' am I making?

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I am using the R packahe **twitteR** to pull some tweet information from the Twitter API.
I log in via OAuth as follows:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
```

This works fine. I then use the function `searchTwitter` to get the information for 15 search terms (smaller example below) using the following loop:

```
searchTerms <- c(`term1` = "Barrack Obama",
                 `term2` = "Donald Duck")

for(i in 1:length(terms)) {

    raw_tweets[[i]] <- searchTwitter(searchTerms[i], n = 99999,
                                     since = as.Date(Sys.time()),
                                     lang = "en", resultType = 'recent')
}
```

This does work - however I get timed out several times during the process  (this shorter example likely won't!) and so need to wait roughly "15 minutes **minus** time taken to use all alotted 180 requests"

I was under the impression I was making 15 requests and so could easily get all data in one go.

What am I missing? Does one day count as one request?

This shows me the limits on my running connection with the API:

```
my_limits <- twitteR::getCurRateLimitInfo()
```

the only value that seems to be affected (from the 64 categories) is that of `/search/tweets`:

```
> my_limits[61,]
       resource         limit   remaining   reset
  61   /search/tweets   180     180         2016-02-05 21:54:57
```

I can't find any extra information on the [dev website](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting) regarding what actually constitutes as **one** use of a resource - neither can I find anything in [the source code of the package](https://github.com/cran/twitteR/tree/master/R) which helps me.

As I am using this function and am so not familiar with the *actual* API interface through `json` I cannot provide any more information.

Comment: I'd say you are able to make 180 calls to [`/search/tweets`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), where each call returns up to 100 tweets. One `searchTwitter` call may encapsulate many api calls. So in order to return 99999 tweets, you'd need over an hour...

Comment: Seems like a good explanation, thanks for the link. From the `twitteR` documentation I could only find the following: _retryOnRateLimit: If non-zero the search command will block retry up to
          X times if the rate limit is experienced. This might lead to
          a much longer run time but the task will eventually complete
          if the retry count is high enough_. This has luckily been the case for me - but good to know that I could maybe precompute the required time (including blocked timeouts) if I can estimate the number of tweets I will receive for my query.